# Proving a result by making discriminant zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> If the roots of given Quadratic equation 
>   $$a(b-c)x^2 +b(c-a)x + c(a-b)=0$$ 
>   are equal, prove the following:
>   $$\frac{2}{b}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}$$.

**MY approach**:

Method 1: put Discriminant=0 and get stuck.

Method2:add $acx$ on both sides and get $(x-1)$ as factor ,so other root is also 1 and hence the result.
But if someone can prove the result by making discriminant zero (method 1), that would be more rigorous.
Thank you.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to work it directly using discriminant, but your method2 is rly clever!

Comment: @ganeshie8  grace of ganesh hehehe

Answer (score 9):

Following your first approach, we have that the discriminant is
$$\begin{align}
\Delta&=b^2(c−a)^2-4a(b−c)c(a−b)\\
&=b^2(c−a)^2+4ac(b^2-b(a+c)+ac)\\
&=b^2(c+a)^2+(2ac)^2-2b(a+c)(2ac)\\
&=(b(a+c)-2ac)^2
\end{align}.$$
and by letting $\Delta=0$, it is easy to show that $\frac{2}{b}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}$.

As regards your second approach, since you already noted that $x=1$ is a root, we have a double root if and only if the following polynomial identity holds (polynomial factorization is unique):
$$a(b-c)x^2 +b(c-a)x + c(a-b)=0=a(b-c)(x-1)^2.$$
Now by letting $x=0$ we find $$c(a-b)=a(b-c)$$ which implies $\frac{2}{b}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}$.

Comment: How did you get that in just one step? I mean... is it an obvious identity or result?

Comment: @ab123 I was actually writing up something more or less along these lines. I didn't bother doing the tedious stuff, I just dumped the quadratic into Wolfram, told it to find the discriminant, and lo and behold one of the alternative forms worked: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+the+discriminant+of+a%28b-c%29x%5E2++%2B+b%28a-c%29x+%2B+c%28a-b%29)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer wow! Wolfram is quite intelligent

Comment: @ab123 Wolfram is a big help here, but you can do it also by hand...

Comment: @RobertZ much more understandable after the edit, thanks!

Comment: @RobertZ how can you arbitrarily let x=0?

Comment: @GeorgeCarlin Because $a(b-c)x^2 +b(c-a)x + c(a-b)=0=a(b-c)(x-1)^2$ is a polynomial identity which holds for any $x$. I edited my answer.

Comment: What you wrote is not an identity. The identity is $$ a(b-c)x^2+b(c-a)x+c(a-b)-a(b-c)(x-1)^2=(x-1)(ab+bc-2ac)$$ for all $\,a,b,c,x.\,$ Now if the left side is $0$ and $\,x\ne 1\,$ then we get $\,ab+bc-2ac=0.$

Answer (score 2):

If you label:
$$\begin{cases}a(b-c)=p\\
b(c-a)=q\\
c(a-b)=r\end{cases} \Rightarrow p+q+r=0$$
then the equation becomes:
$$px^2+qx+r=0,\\
D=q^2-4pr=(-p-r)^2-4pr=(p-r)^2=0 \Rightarrow p=r\Rightarrow \\
a(b-c)=c(a-b) \Rightarrow 2ac=ab+bc \stackrel{\cdot \frac1{abc}}{\Rightarrow} \frac2b=\frac1a+\frac1c.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $a(b-c)+b(c-a)+c(a-b)=0$, you know that $x=1$ is a root, as you observed.

With synthetic division by $x-1$, we get, assuming $a\ne0$ and $b\ne c$,
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
  & ab-ac      & bc-ab & ac-bc \\
1 & \downarrow & ab-ac & bc-ac \\
\hline
  & ab-ac      & bc-ac & 0
\end{array}
$$
The other root is
$$
-\frac{bc-ac}{ab-ac}
$$
Therefore $bc-ac=-ab+ac$ is the condition that the equation has two equal roots. This becomes
$$
2ac=bc+ab
$$
and, dividing by $abc$, we get
$$
\frac{2}{b}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}
$$

If $a=0$ or $b=c$ the equation is not a quadratic. Can it be $b=0$? In this case we get $-acx^2+ac=0$ and we need $c\ne0$; the roots are $1$ and $-1$. With $c=0$ it would be the same.